# Creating/Writing to Sharded (Dated) BigQuery table via Google Cloud Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam-io

Is there an easy to follow example how to configure a streaming mode Dataflow Pipeline to write each window into a separate BigQuery table (and create one, if necessary)?

I.e. - table_20160701, table_20160702, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sample code:

`

```
PCollection<TableRow> quotes = 
  quotes.apply(Window.<TableRow>into(CalendarWindows.days(1)))
        .apply(BigQueryIO.Write
          .named("Write")
          .withSchema(schema)
          .to(new SerializableFunction<BoundedWindow, String>() {
            public String apply(BoundedWindow window) {
              // The cast below is safe because CalendarWindows.days(1) produces IntervalWindows.
              String dayString = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy_MM_dd")
                   .withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC)
                   .print(((IntervalWindow) window).start());
              return "my-project:output.output_table_" + dayString;
            }
          }));
  }
```

`

Taken from here:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/BigQueryIO.java